# -DNDEBUG with -Ofast is slower than only -Ofast

Tags: c, gcc, optimization

I'm in the process of optimizing a simple [genetic algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm) and [neural network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_neural_network), and I'm fiddling with some options in GCC to generate faster executables.

In my code I have some assertions, such as

```
mat mat_add(mat a, mat b)
{
    assert(a->rows == b->rows);
    assert(a->cols == b->cols);
    mat m = mat_create(a->rows, a->cols);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < a->rows; i++) {
        for(size_t j = 0; j < a->cols; j++)
            mat_set(m, i, j, mat_get(a, i, j) + mat_get(b, i, j));
    }
    return m;
}
```

I've figured that if I added [-DNDEBUG](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#index-D-1) to disable the assertions, the executable would be faster because it wouldn't check the conditions above. However, it is actually slower.

Without `-DNDEBUG`:

`gcc src/*.c -lm -pthread -Iinclude/ -Wall -Ofast` 
`for i in $(seq 1 5); do time ./a.out; done`

Output:

```
real    0m11.677s
user    1m28.786s
sys     0m0.729s

real    0m11.716s
user    1m29.304s
sys     0m0.723s

real    0m12.217s
user    1m31.707s
sys     0m0.806s

real    0m12.602s
user    1m32.863s
sys     0m0.726s

real    0m12.225s
user    1m30.915s
sys     0m0.736s
```

With `-DNDEBUG`:

`gcc src/*.c -lm -pthread -Iinclude/ -Wall -Ofast -DNDEBUG` 
`for i in $(seq 1 5); do time ./a.out; done`

Output:

```
real    0m13.698s
user    1m42.533s
sys     0m0.792s

real    0m13.764s
user    1m43.337s
sys     0m0.709s

real    0m13.655s
user    1m42.986s
sys     0m0.739s

real    0m13.836s
user    1m43.138s
sys     0m0.719s

real    0m14.072s
user    1m43.879s
sys     0m0.712s
```

It isn't much slower, but it is noticeable.

What could be causing this slowdown?

Comment: I don't know the asnwer, but did you try creating local copies of `size_t arows = a->rows` and `size_t brows = b->rows`. I have seen this a possible optimization since the loop doesn't have to check the value by pointer indirection all the time. (after all, they can be being changed in other threads.) Perhaps the assert is helping the compiler to create effective a local copy of these two.

Comment: @alfC I've tried your suggestion and the performance has indeed improved by roughly 0.5s. I wonder why the pointer indirection can be optimized away when using the asserts though, since the values can still change after those assertions.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but are the definitions of `mat_get` and `mat_set` visible in the same translation unit (e.g. inline functions in a header)? If not, you're wasting your time chasing tiny gains with optimization flags (and risking breaking things, since `-Ofast` performs invalid transformations) and should make them inlinable, or better yet, get rid of the accessor functions and use a 2d array directly. This would probably make an order of magnitude difference.

Comment: @Demindiro, I am not an expert but I think `-Ofast` can do non-legal optimizations and that itself can drive you into crazy scenarios. Did you test with `-O3`? maybe it will make sense with then, even if you get slower runtimes overall.

Comment: Check the generated code and you will have the answer. Guessing is pointless

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do the `mat_set` and `mat_get` functions perform their own bounds checks on the indices? With the asserts present, the loop is only reachable if `b->rows == a->rows` is true. That allows the compiler to optimize out any check `i < b->rows` in the `mat_get` for `b`, because it knows `b->rows == a->rows` and `i < a->rows` by the loop condition.

If this ends up being the case, you could achieve the same without assertions, and without any runtime branch, by adding (GNU C feature):

```
if (a->rows != b->rows || a->cols != b->cols)
    __builtin_unreachable();
```

A more portable but less reliable way to do this is just write some nonsensical undefined behavior like `1/0;` in the `if` body.